# Creating BlobstoreKey from GoogleCloudStorage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I'm writting this code for a project using GAE. Im not using Blobstore but i need to use the servingUrl method.

```
    GcsFilename gcsFilename = new GcsFilename(myBucket, myFileName);
        BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey(
    "/gs/" + gcsFilename.getBucketName() + "/" + gcsFilename.getObjectName());

ImagesService images = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
    GcsFilename gcsFilename = new GcsFilename(myBucket, myFileName);
    BlobstoreService blobstore = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    BlobKey blobKey = blobstore.createGsBlobKey(key);
    ServingUrlOptions opts = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.
            withBlobKey(blobKey).
            secureUrl(true);
    images.getServingUrl(opts);
```

When I execute one of this codes, im getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'blobstore' or call 'CreateEncodedGoogleStorageKey()' was not found.

Any idea?

Comment: Which line of you code throws this exception?

Comment: @LaiaxanIV Got the solution for this? If so please share. Even 'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @das Yes, I edited my question

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LaiaxanIV's solution posted as an edit to the question:

> SOLUTION I FOUND:
>
> ```
> String key = ""; // Such as /gs/example-bucket/categories/animals.png"
> ImagesService images = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
> BlobstoreService blobstore = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
> BlobKey blobKey = blobstore.createGsBlobKey(key);
> ServingUrlOptions opts = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.
>         withBlobKey(blobKey).
>         secureUrl(true);
> return images.getServingUrl(opts);
> ```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Dan, I tried this solution but still getting the same error. Can you please let me know if you got solution for this?                                                                                                      Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't really, I'm using python :) This is LaiaxanIV's solution.