# getServingUrl() Method using Google Cloud Storage value in Java throws exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-java-client, google-app-engine-python

I have been trying the code block to generate Google Cloud image url using Java, where my-bucket is the Google Storage bucket name.

```
String key = "/gs/Buckets/my-bucket/photo/1/content.jpeg"; 
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder
        .withGoogleStorageFileName(key)
        .imageSize(100);
String servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(options);
```

But I am getting error as

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'blobstore' or call 'CreateEncodedGoogleStorageKey()' was not found.
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:111)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:66)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.createGsBlobKey(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:312)
at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.getServingUrl(ImagesServiceImpl.java:266)
at com.example.appengine.images.ImagesServlet.main(ImagesServlet.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I have tried the key values

```
String key = "/gs/Buckets/my-bucket/photo/1/content.jpeg";
```

and

```
String key = "/gs/my-bucket/photo/1/content.jpeg";
```

But this gets the same error.

### Update

Tried this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42333834/4909177, and getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating BlobstoreKey from GoogleCloudStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310077/creating-blobstorekey-from-googlecloudstorage)

Comment: @DanCornilescu Tried that, getting the same error.

Comment: @das I am also getting the same error, can you please let me know if you got the solution for this?                                                                                                        
Thanks in Advance.